# Python Selenium send_keys(Keys.RETURN) function does not work

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Every time when I'm using `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` it does not coniform my input. There is just a □ symbol. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` instead